# wso2 store - how to add custom page

Tags: wso2, store, wso2-api-manager, custom-pages

I would like to know if it's possible to create a new custom page in store.

If yes, where will be stored this page ?

maybe in

```
site/themes/fancy/subthemes/<mySubTheme>/templates/
```

Is there any template to follow?

Thank you in advance

Claudio

Comment: Have you visited https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Adding+a+new+API+Store+Theme ?

Comment: Hi Abimaran, I don't need to add or change the theme, but I would to add a new page that will be visibile clicking on a link on the footer, I found a guide on this, but seems incomplete...

Comment: Well, I finally manage it! I have successfully added a new linkable page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this interesting guide

[Api Manager](http://www.slideshare.net/wso2.org/customizing-the-api-store-publisher-in-the-wso2-api-manager)